# rspec error with user_path(@user)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have this test:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "LayoutLinks" do
  I18n.available_locales.each do |locale|
    I18n.locale = locale
    .
    .

    describe "when signed in" do
      before(:each) do
        @user = Factory(:user)
        visit signin_path
        fill_in :email,    :with => @user.email
        fill_in :password, :with => @user.password
        click_button
        visit root_path
      end

      .
      .
      .
      it "should have a profile link" do
        response.should have_selector('a', :href => "/#{I18n.locale}#{user_path(@user)}", :content => I18n.t(:link_profile))
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I work with the language selection in the url. Like /en/... or /de/...

This test gets this error Message:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users", :locale=>#<the complete User Hash>
```

I guess from the error Message that the complete User hash is put into the locale part of the url, How is that done or how could I prevent this?

€Edit I found the solution:

I had to pass the locale variable to the `user_path(@user)` in this way:

`response.should have_selector('a', :href => user_path(I18n.locale, @user), :content => I1`

Comment: When do you get this error? In each test (so the view is rendering wrong) or only in the test `it 'should have a profile link'` ?

Comment: The error occured only on the profile link test. But I found the solution:
I had to pass the locale variable to the user_path(@user) in this way:

response.should have_selector('a', :href => user_path(I18n.locale, @user), :content => I1